# How to push values to the rootViewController from NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following problem:

I would like to pass some data to my rootViewController, from an UINavigationController in an Popover. My popover is here:

```
var popoverNavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popoverNavigationController") as! PopoverNavigationController
```

When ill open that controller with:

```
popoverController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
self.presentViewController(popoverController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

There is a rootViewcontroller, with a certain class - how could i append data from the NavigationController to its rootViewController?

For example:

```
popoverController.text = "1234"
```

How can i push this value to the rootViewController? The NavigationController is initialized by the Storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: can you explain the your viewcontroller hierarchy a bit more? maybe show an image or something? i'm kinda confused... :)

Comment: Thanks - added the Image. The Problem here is that the Popover View Controller is loaded directly from storyboard, and not with a segue.

Comment: maybe the complete screen? :) and then tell me again from which vc you want to pass data to which vc?

Comment: There are about 70 ViewControllers, so most is senseless here. Ill just want to push data from Popover View Controller to Popover Add Items View Controller in Screen (its the rootViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got you right in your navigationcontroller you could do something like this:

```
if let rootViewController = viewControllers.first as? PopoverAddItemsViewController {
  rootViewController.text = "1234"
}
```